# Get current Blog ID in Tinymce Plugin Dialog Window in WPMU

Tags: multisite, tinymce, blog-id

is there any way, to get the current blog id in a Tinymce Dialog Window? Currently I only get the id, from the main blog. This is my current code:

```
$wp_load = "wp-load.php";
while(!file_exists($wp_load)) {
$wp_load = '../' . $wp_load;
if(file_exists($wp_load)){
    break;
}
}
require_once($wp_load);
global $blog_id;
echo $blog_id;
$blog = get_blog_details($blog_id);
```

Any help is welcome.

Lars

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
global $current_blog;
$blog = get_blog_details($current_blog->blog_id);
```